# Bringing in KML into Google Earth with different Coordinate System

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth, wgs84

I have a shapefile (in red outline bellow) that has the following attribute:

Projected Coordinate System: NAD_1927_StatePlane_Wyoming_East_Central_FIPS_4902
Projection: Transverse_Mercator

But when I export the shapefile to KML/KMZ so I can view it in Google Earth, the polygon does not align to where the shapefile appears in ArcMap. I can tell because in ArcMap the road is inside the polygon and in Google Earth it's clearly outside see images below)

I've read that Google Earth uses WGS 1984 as its projection, so I projected the shapefile to WGS 1984, exported it to KML/KMZ and still the polygon does not fall in the right place (see purple polygon in image 2) - the road is still out side of the polygon.
Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What geographic/datum transformation was used to convert between NAD27 and WGS84?

Comment: I used the "Project" tool in ArcMap. Transformation: NAD_1927_to_NAD_1983_NADCON+NAD_1983_to_WGS_1984_1

Comment: Sorry, next question! In ArcMap, is there a transformation set? If it is, use the same one in the Project Tool.

Comment: You men, under View>Data Frame Properties...>Transformation?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: It didn't work. I get the same results. Unless, WGS 1984 is not the GCS in Google Earth

Comment: @doronwen, can you share the shapefile?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca unfortunately I cant share the shapefile, but I can share the properties. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @doronwen, if you can share the coordinates of the geometry, other users could find the transformation you are looking for and answer your question.

Comment: Projected Coordinate System: NAD_1927_StatePlane_Wyoming_East_Central_FIPS_4902

Projection: Transverse_Mercator

False_Easting: 500000.00000000

False_Northing: 0.00000000

Central_Meridian: -107.33333333

Scale_Factor: 0.99994118

Latitude_Of_Origin: 40.66666667

Linear Unit:  Foot_US


Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1927

Datum:  D_North_American_1927

Prime Meridian:  Greenwich

Angular Unit:  Degree